# Errors in ProfileDeployAction: Failed to add deployment in deployment in JBOSS

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I am getting the following error on Jboss 6.x

```
17:09:22,216 ERROR [org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction] Failed to add deployment: GISManager.ear: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Exception determining structure: AbstractVFSDeployment(GISManager.ear)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.structure.spi.helpers.AbstractStructuralDeployers.determineStructure(AbstractStructuralDeployers.java:85) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.determineStructure(MainDeployerImpl.java:1106) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.determineDeploymentContext(MainDeployerImpl.java:417) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.addDeployment(MainDeployerImpl.java:367) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.addDeployment(MainDeployerImpl.java:277) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.addDeployment(MainDeployerPlugin.java:77) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.addDeployment(ProfileControllerContext.java:133) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:132) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:154) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.system.tools.ProfileServiceToolsFacade.addURI(ProfileServiceToolsFacade.java:233) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.tools.LegacyDeploymentScannerAdapter.addURL(LegacyDeploymentScannerAdapter.java:140) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.tools.DeploymentScanner.addURL(DeploymentScanner.java:91) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.tools.DeploymentScanner.addURL(DeploymentScanner.java:83) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [:1.7.0_25]
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:271) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:670) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.jmx.MBeanServerWrapper.invoke(MBeanServerWrapper.java:138) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487) [:1.7.0_25]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97) [:1.7.0_25]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328) [:1.7.0_25]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420) [:1.7.0_25]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848) [:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322) [:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177) [:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174) [:1.7.0_25]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173) [:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553) [:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808) [:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667) [:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [:1.7.0_25]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error determining structure: GISManager.ear
    at org.jboss.deployment.EARStructure.doDetermineStructure(EARStructure.java:291) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.AbstractVFSArchiveStructureDeployer.determineStructure(AbstractVFSArchiveStructureDeployer.java:60) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.StructureDeployerWrapper.determineStructure(StructureDeployerWrapper.java:73) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.doDetermineStructure(VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.java:197) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.determineStructure(VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.java:222) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.structure.spi.helpers.AbstractStructuralDeployers.determineStructure(AbstractStructuralDeployers.java:77) [:2.2.2.GA]
    ... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: gismanager-common.jar module listed in application.xml does not exist within .ear vfs:///D:/BlazeDSWorkSpace/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_6.x_Runtime_Server1385622191375/deploy/GISManager.ear/
    at org.jboss.deployment.EARStructure.doDetermineStructure(EARStructure.java:262) [:6.1.0.Final]
    ... 65 more

17:09:22,230 ERROR [org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction] Failed to add deployment: FirstaidProject.ear: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Exception determining structure: AbstractVFSDeployment(FirstaidProject.ear)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.structure.spi.helpers.AbstractStructuralDeployers.determineStructure(AbstractStructuralDeployers.java:85) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.determineStructure(MainDeployerImpl.java:1106) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.determineDeploymentContext(MainDeployerImpl.java:417) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.addDeployment(MainDeployerImpl.java:367) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.addDeployment(MainDeployerImpl.java:277) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.addDeployment(MainDeployerPlugin.java:77) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.addDeployment(ProfileControllerContext.java:133) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:132) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:154) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.system.tools.ProfileServiceToolsFacade.addURI(ProfileServiceToolsFacade.java:233) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.tools.LegacyDeploymentScannerAdapter.addURL(LegacyDeploymentScannerAdapter.java:140) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.tools.DeploymentScanner.addURL(DeploymentScanner.java:91) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.tools.DeploymentScanner.addURL(DeploymentScanner.java:83) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [:1.7.0_25]
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:271) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:670) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.jmx.MBeanServerWrapper.invoke(MBeanServerWrapper.java:138) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487) [:1.7.0_25]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97) [:1.7.0_25]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328) [:1.7.0_25]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420) [:1.7.0_25]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848) [:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322) [:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177) [:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174) [:1.7.0_25]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173) [:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553) [:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808) [:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667) [:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [:1.7.0_25]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error determining structure: FirstaidProject.ear
    at org.jboss.deployment.EARStructure.doDetermineStructure(EARStructure.java:291) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.AbstractVFSArchiveStructureDeployer.determineStructure(AbstractVFSArchiveStructureDeployer.java:60) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.StructureDeployerWrapper.determineStructure(StructureDeployerWrapper.java:73) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.doDetermineStructure(VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.java:197) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.determineStructure(VFSStructuralDeployersImpl.java:222) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.structure.spi.helpers.AbstractStructuralDeployers.determineStructure(AbstractStructuralDeployers.java:77) [:2.2.2.GA]
    ... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: lmkt-core.jar module listed in application.xml does not exist within .ear vfs:///D:/BlazeDSWorkSpace/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_6.x_Runtime_Server1385622191375/deploy/FirstaidProject.ear/
    at org.jboss.deployment.EARStructure.doDetermineStructure(EARStructure.java:262) [:6.1.0.Final]
    ... 65 more
```

Comment: Try to format your post properly so others can read it easily

Answer (score 0):

The stack-trace is self-explanatory

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: gismanager-common.jar module listed in application.xml does not exist within .ear
.....
.....
java.lang.RuntimeException: lmkt-core.jar module listed in application.xml does not exist within .ear
```

You are missing required jars `gismanager-common.jar` and `lmkt-core.jar` in your `GisManager.ear` and `FirstAidProject.ear` respectively